# How to forecast data based on variables from different datasets?

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

For a university project I’m trying to see the relation oil production/consumption and crude oil price have on certain oil stocks, and I’m a bit confused about how to sort this data.

I basically have 4 datasets-
-Oil production
-Oil consumption
-Crude oil price
-Historical price of certain oil company stock

If I am trying to find a way these 4 tables relate, what is the recommended way of organizing the data? Should I manually combine all this data to a single Excel sheet (seems like the most straight-forward way) or is there a more efficient way to go about this.

I am brand new to PyTorch and data, so I apologise if this is a very basic question. Also, the data can basically get infinitely larger, by adding data from additional countries, other stock indexes, etc. So is there a way I can organize the data so it’s easy to add additional related data?

Finally, I have the month-to-month values for certain data (eg: oil production), and day-to-day values for other data (eg: oil price). What is the best way I can adjust the data to make up for this discrepancy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame` to create 4 dataframes for each dataset, then proceed with combining them in one dataframe by using `merge`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

So basically it's best to have all data in one database right? In that case, I would assume the best way to go about it, assuming I want to constantly update data, would be to create a massive, well organised excel database with all the data, which then automatically updates.